# Canonical models of Teichmüller curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, teichmuller-theory

It is well-known that Shimura varieties can be defined over number fields and that moreover they possess canonical model over number fields. On the other hand, Teichmüller curves can also be defined over number fields. Do Teichmüller curves have canonical models? what are effective or helpful results in this direction?

Answer (score 4):

The state of the art on the arithmetic geometry of Teichmuller curves is the following paper, which also has a good bibliography: http://arxiv.org/abs/1406.7057.  For specific questions, I recommend emailing Ronen Mukamel, who also has quite a bit of work on this kind of stuff that he has not written up.